# Is there/should there be a way to actively "cross-promote" relevant questions across SEs?

Tags: discussion, site-crossover

A very interesting question: [Intersection Between Computer Science and History?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/1660/intersection-between-computer-science-and-history)

Which SE does this really belong on? Could it (and should it) be cross-posted or shared between communities?

It seems as though a user of history.SE with a strong CS knowledge could answer it, but a user of another relevant SE with history knowledge could also provide something useful.

Is there a mechanism (other than the popular question "ads") for sharing questions that cross SEs' areas of expertise?

Comment: Looks as though "someone with a degree in history, and a degree in computer science" has weighed in, so it may be in the perfect place already?

Comment: That question seems way too broad for any of the sites you listed.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The more I thought of it, the more it seemed that way. History seems to be the right home for it, I'll update the title to reflect the crux of the question (in the last paragraph_

Answer (score 1):

Definitely CS, as the question itself asking about Computers science and its history. It is more likely to attract good attention in CS.